# SQl 2 XLS with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xls

Is there a good PHP Class to export data from mysql to XLS file?

Comment: Unless any of your included files generate output, this will give you a blank page. The xls file is being written to the current working directory on the server's filesystem... and there is nothing here to display it in the browser, or initiate a file save dialogue.

Comment: Either change the filename in the save to $objWriter->save('php://output'); or add readfile('CityList.xls'); immediately after the save (having sent the appropriate http response headings for an xls file first);

Comment: Look at the examples in the /Tests directory of the PHPExcel distribution, particularly 01simple-download-xls.php

Comment: It would have been better to raise another question, rather than editing this one; or at least to have left the original question visible.

Comment: Question? There is no question.

Comment: @symcbean - the problem/question is actually in the comments to my answer to the previous question that mini has edited/replaced... namely "it don't work". I've already answered it... namely, it should work: this code __will__ return a blank page, check for the Excel file in the filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to do this using the [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) library. It won't read the database for you; but you can easily write a script that reads the database, then build up a worksheet as you loop through the rows.

**EDIT**

Read the documentation, look at the example code:

```
require_once './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    // Create a new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List of Cities');

    // Loop through the result set
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($row,NULL,'A'.$rowNumber++);
    }
    // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('CityList.xls');
}
```

Comment: I have one more question. How can I assign the data from mysql to the class.

Comment: Loop through the rows from the database, and use the PHPExcel_Worksheet's fromArray() method to write each row (use the advanced value binder if you need to handle dates, so that they're automatically converted to Excel dates, and formatted appropriately)

Comment: I just edit the code above. But I get an empty page. I don't know why

Comment: I don't know why either... without seeing your code, I can't tell if there's any errors, or what you might be doing. My example code writes the file to the server disk, but doesn't echo anything to screen. Is the file created? Are you writing to a php://output file (ie the browser) or subsequently sending the written file to the browser? Have you looked at any of the examples in the PHPExcel /Tests directory, or read any of the documentation?

Comment: I just rewrite a simple demo (edited my question above)  Still Can't debug the error (blank page)

Answer (score 0):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is a PHP based mySQL interface that supports exporting to Excel. It's an application and not a standalone class, though.

Comment: Yes I want to implement a PHP file to do that. from my dashboard.